# Jquery Submit the Fields in the table for which the input has changed

Tags: jquery, json

Hello I am trying to submit the form table in the JSON format. I am able to get the form table data in JSON format. But I wish to only submit the data for those input fields whose input has been changed.

Here is my Code -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.serializeJSON/2.9.0/jquery.serializejson.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="otherpage.html">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Field 1</th>
        <th>Field 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="field1[]">id1</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="field2[]">dsda</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="field1[]">id2</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="field2[]">dsda</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In every `tr` there is a hidden field as well, so when I submit the form and fill only for Field1 i.e ID for first `tr`. I want to submit the data only for that `tr and skip the second all input boxes for second tr, if the input field is not changed.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible strategy can be:

- on dom ready set a data attribute for each input with its initial value
- on button click filter input elements in order to get only the modified ones

```js
$('#form input').each(function(idx, ele) {
    $(ele).data('initValue', ele.value); // save values at begin...
});

$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    // get only the modified fields...
    var changedElements = $('#form input').filter(function(idx, ele) {
        return this.value != $(ele).data('initValue');
    });
    var fs = changedElements.serializeJSON();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(fs));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.serializeJSON/2.9.0/jquery.serializejson.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="otherpage.html">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1</th>
            <th>Field 2</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="field11[]">id1</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="field21[]">dsda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="field12[]">id2</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="field22[]">dsda</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" name="button" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```